# Как установить библиотеки Си/С++ через терминал линукса?

Tags: c++, c

Я питонист и слышал, что в Си устанавливать библиотеки сложно, но не думал, что настолько)

Я облазел все: Ютуб, Гугл, соц-сети, остался только твич)...

Я использовал make, но все равно выдало ошибку
P.s. другие способы даже не привели ни к чему, а make ещё, что-то сделал...

Так же, я задал этот вопрос в mail.otvet, но мне сказали, что я дебил и попросили научиться пользоваться яндексом

Не знаю, мб, я скачал фигню, а не библиотеки с инета, поэтому не работает...

Если что, я хочу установить библиотеку **conio.h**

Comment: conio.h — это не библиотека, а заголовочный файл

Comment: Что!? Я смотрел видео на Ютубе и мне сказали, что это библиотека...)

Comment: Бл, ок, запомню

Comment: Более того, conio.h - нестандартный заголовочный файл (буквально - не входящий в стандарты C и С++), насколько я помню - специфичный только для  Borland/Embarcadero С++ Builder и возможно для С++ компилятора от Microsoft (входящего в Microsoft Visual Studio). Для других компиляторов нужно использовать другие средства (зависит от того, что конкретно вам из этого файла нужно)

Comment: conio.h файл специфичный для DOS,Windows. Вы не найдёте его на Linux. Аналогичная функциональность есть в `ncurses`, но вам придётся изменять ваш код при переходе с conio на ncurses. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8792443/14775762.